# Setup of Salamander Lemma

Tags: homological-algebra

On ncatlab, in explaining the basics of the Salamander lemma, they state the following.

[image]

For $A_{\square}$, they write the denominator as $\operatorname{im}(\partial^{hor}_{in}) \oplus \operatorname{im}(\partial^{vert}_{in})$. Why are they using the direct sum here? Those two modules aren't disjoint, are they?

Comment: Probably not relevant anymore, but anyways … This was indeed a mistake and has been corrected. The direct sum has been replaced by the sum of submodules of $\operatorname{ker}(\partial^{\operatorname{diag}}_{\operatorname{out}})$ (, i.e. the join in the lattice of submodules of $\operatorname{ker}(\partial^{\operatorname{diag}}_{\operatorname{out}})$ ordered by inclusion).